# Error when running composer update: Script @symfony-scripts handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.2 and am trying to run a `composer update` command. This composer file attached to a brand new install. The complete error is:

> Script @symfony-scripts handling the post-update-cmd event returned
>   with an error [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output: sh: @symfony-scripts: command not found

I can't find any information on what this means or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 7):

This was actually a composer issue and nothing to do with Symfony or it's vendor files. I needed to run `composer selfupdate` and then I could successfully run `composer update`

Answer (score -4):

I solved it by editing the following in composer.json

change:

[image]

for:

[image]

Comment: Pushing the dust under the rug isn't a real solution.